# How can I improve performance of queries with window-functions, that seem to ignore indexes?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle-apex, query-performance

How can I improve performance of queries with window-functions, that seem to ignore indexes?
Or, are there additional indexes I need to create?
Or, can I eliminate self-joins from my final query?

I have a query with window functions, and I need to get it running smoothly.
I could remove the window functions, and switch to `GROUP BY` - but I think that would be slower?

This query is used inside views, for external reports that are pulled frequently.
In other words, this query is executed frequently by end-users, in some cases numerous times for large reports, and the end-user is directly impacted by the time this query takes to execute.
Currently, the query executes pretty quickly as-is - but later on, I have to self-join this query to itself, and it slows to a crawl.

The underlying table has an index defined on every single column referenced.
But when I `EXPLAIN` this query, it isn't using any of the indexes, and performs a full table scan instead.

The table currently has 28,000 rows, but that will increase over time (about 10,000 rows per day).

The `EDGE_VP`, `EDGE_RM`, and `EDGE_ASM` columns contain an e-mail address - string functions remove the domain.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SS_TIMESTAMP,
                CASE WHEN INSTR(EDGE_VP,'@oracle.com')=0 THEN EDGE_VP ELSE SUBSTR(EDGE_VP,1,INSTR(EDGE_VP,'@oracle.com')-1) END AS EDGE_VP,
                CASE WHEN INSTR(EDGE_RM,'@oracle.com')=0 THEN EDGE_RM ELSE SUBSTR(EDGE_RM,1,INSTR(EDGE_RM,'@oracle.com')-1) END AS EDGE_RM,
                CASE WHEN INSTR(EDGE_ASM,'@oracle.com')=0 THEN EDGE_ASM ELSE SUBSTR(EDGE_ASM,1,INSTR(EDGE_ASM,'@oracle.com')-1) END AS EDGE_ASM,
                NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN OPPTY_STATUS = 'Open' THEN ARR_PIPELINE END) OVER (PARTITION BY SS_TIMESTAMP, EDGE_VP, EDGE_RM, EDGE_ASM),0) AS PIPELINE,
                NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN OPPTY_STATUS = 'Open' THEN ARR_BEST END) OVER (PARTITION BY SS_TIMESTAMP, EDGE_VP, EDGE_RM, EDGE_ASM),0) AS BEST,
                NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN OPPTY_STATUS = 'Open' THEN ARR_FORECAST END) OVER (PARTITION BY SS_TIMESTAMP, EDGE_VP, EDGE_RM, EDGE_ASM),0) AS FORECAST,
                NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN OPPTY_STATUS = 'Won' THEN ARR END) OVER (PARTITION BY SS_TIMESTAMP, EDGE_VP, EDGE_RM, EDGE_ASM),0) AS CLOSED,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SS_TIMESTAMP, EDGE_VP, EDGE_RM, EDGE_ASM) AS ROW_COUNT
FROM SS_EDGE_FORECAST
WHERE EDGE_ASM NOT IN('Email_Address1', 'Email_Address2')
```

**CLICK IMAGES TO ENLARGE:**

[image]

[image]

Here's the expanded query I'm using later on.
**Notice the query at the top, in the `WITH` clause.**
At the end of this query, I am currently using self-joins of the `WITH` query - maybe I should use window-functions here as well?

I can't tell you how long this takes to execute, because it hangs when I try to run it, and I don't have patience to wait for hours etc.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "EDGE_FORECAST_OVER_TIME" AS
WITH basequery AS (SELECT DISTINCT SS_TIMESTAMP,
                                   CASE WHEN INSTR(EDGE_VP,'@oracle.com')=0 THEN EDGE_VP ELSE SUBSTR(EDGE_VP,1,INSTR(EDGE_VP,'@oracle.com')-1) END AS EDGE_VP,
                                   CASE WHEN INSTR(EDGE_RM,'@oracle.com')=0 THEN EDGE_RM ELSE SUBSTR(EDGE_RM,1,INSTR(EDGE_RM,'@oracle.com')-1) END AS EDGE_RM,
                                   CASE WHEN INSTR(EDGE_ASM,'@oracle.com')=0 THEN EDGE_ASM ELSE SUBSTR(EDGE_ASM,1,INSTR(EDGE_ASM,'@oracle.com')-1) END AS EDGE_ASM,
                                   NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN OPPTY_STATUS = 'Open' THEN ARR_PIPELINE END) OVER (PARTITION BY SS_TIMESTAMP, EDGE_VP, EDGE_RM, EDGE_ASM),0) AS PIPELINE,
                                   NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN OPPTY_STATUS = 'Open' THEN ARR_BEST END) OVER (PARTITION BY SS_TIMESTAMP, EDGE_VP, EDGE_RM, EDGE_ASM),0) AS BEST,
                                   NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN OPPTY_STATUS = 'Open' THEN ARR_FORECAST END) OVER (PARTITION BY SS_TIMESTAMP, EDGE_VP, EDGE_RM, EDGE_ASM),0) AS FORECAST,
                                   NVL(SUM(CASE WHEN OPPTY_STATUS = 'Won' THEN ARR END) OVER (PARTITION BY SS_TIMESTAMP, EDGE_VP, EDGE_RM, EDGE_ASM),0) AS CLOSED,
                                   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SS_TIMESTAMP, EDGE_VP, EDGE_RM, EDGE_ASM) AS ROW_COUNT
                   FROM SS_EDGE_FORECAST
                   WHERE EDGE_ASM NOT IN('Email_Address1', 'Email_Address2'))
SELECT ss.TIMESTAMP,
       ss.TIMESTAMP_DATE,
       ss.FREQUENCY,
       ss.PREV_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.PREV_F_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.PREV_H_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.PREV_D_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.PREV_W_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.PREV_M_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.PREV_Q_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.PREV_Y_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.PREV_TIMESTAMP_DATE,
       ss.PREV_F_TIMESTAMP_DATE,
       ss.PREV_H_TIMESTAMP_DATE,
       ss.PREV_D_TIMESTAMP_DATE,
       ss.PREV_W_TIMESTAMP_DATE,
       ss.PREV_M_TIMESTAMP_DATE,
       ss.PREV_Q_TIMESTAMP_DATE,
       ss.PREV_Y_TIMESTAMP_DATE,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_F_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_H_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_D_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_W_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_M_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_Q_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_Y_TIMESTAMP,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_TS_DATE,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_F_TS_DATE,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_H_TS_DATE,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_D_TS_DATE,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_W_TS_DATE,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_M_TS_DATE,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_Q_TS_DATE,
       ss.DAYS_SINCE_PREV_Y_TS_DATE,

       bq.EDGE_VP,
       bq.EDGE_RM,
       bq.EDGE_ASM,

       bq.PIPELINE,
       bq.BEST,
       bq.FORECAST,
       bq.CLOSED,
       bq.PIPELINE + bq.BEST AS PIPE_BEST,
       bq.CLOSED + bq.FORECAST AS CLOSED_FORECAST,

       bqp.PIPELINE AS PREV_PIPELINE,
       bqp.BEST AS PREV_BEST,
       bqp.FORECAST AS PREV_FORECAST,
       bqp.CLOSED AS PREV_CLOSED,
       bqp.PIPELINE + bqp.BEST AS PREV_PIPE_BEST,
       bqp.CLOSED + bqp.FORECAST AS PREV_CLOSED_FORECAST,
       bq.PIPELINE - bqp.PIPELINE AS PIPELINE_DIFF,
       bq.BEST - bqp.BEST AS BEST_DIFF,
       bq.FORECAST - bqp.FORECAST AS FORECAST_DIFF,
       bq.CLOSED - bqp.CLOSED AS CLOSED_DIFF,
       (bq.PIPELINE + bq.BEST) - (bqp.PIPELINE + bqp.BEST) AS PIPE_BEST_DIFF,
       (bq.CLOSED + bq.FORECAST) - (bqp.CLOSED + bqp.FORECAST) AS CLOSED_FORECAST_DIFF,

       bqpf.PIPELINE AS PREV_F_PIPELINE,
       bqpf.BEST AS PREV_F_BEST,
       bqpf.FORECAST AS PREV_F_FORECAST,
       bqpf.CLOSED AS PREV_F_CLOSED,
       bqpf.PIPELINE + bqpf.BEST AS PREV_F_PIPE_BEST,
       bqpf.CLOSED + bqpf.FORECAST AS PREV_F_CLOSED_FORECAST,
       bq.PIPELINE - bqpf.PIPELINE AS F_PIPELINE_DIFF,
       bq.BEST - bqpf.BEST AS F_BEST_DIFF,
       bq.FORECAST - bqpf.FORECAST AS F_FORECAST_DIFF,
       bq.CLOSED - bqpf.CLOSED AS F_CLOSED_DIFF,
       (bq.PIPELINE + bq.BEST) - (bqpf.PIPELINE + bqpf.BEST) AS F_PIPE_BEST_DIFF,
       (bq.CLOSED + bq.FORECAST) - (bqpf.CLOSED + bqpf.FORECAST) AS F_CLOSED_FORECAST_DIFF,

       bqph.PIPELINE AS PREV_H_PIPELINE,
       bqph.BEST AS PREV_H_BEST,
       bqph.FORECAST AS PREV_H_FORECAST,
       bqph.CLOSED AS PREV_H_CLOSED,
       bqph.PIPELINE + bqph.BEST AS PREV_H_PIPE_BEST,
       bqph.CLOSED + bqph.FORECAST AS PREV_H_CLOSED_FORECAST,
       bq.PIPELINE - bqph.PIPELINE AS H_PIPELINE_DIFF,
       bq.BEST - bqph.BEST AS H_BEST_DIFF,
       bq.FORECAST - bqph.FORECAST AS H_FORECAST_DIFF,
       bq.CLOSED - bqph.CLOSED AS H_CLOSED_DIFF,
       (bq.PIPELINE + bq.BEST) - (bqph.PIPELINE + bqph.BEST) AS H_PIPE_BEST_DIFF,
       (bq.CLOSED + bq.FORECAST) - (bqph.CLOSED + bqph.FORECAST) AS H_CLOSED_FORECAST_DIFF,

       bqpd.PIPELINE AS PREV_D_PIPELINE,
       bqpd.BEST AS PREV_D_BEST,
       bqpd.FORECAST AS PREV_D_FORECAST,
       bqpd.CLOSED AS PREV_D_CLOSED,
       bqpd.PIPELINE + bqpd.BEST AS PREV_D_PIPE_BEST,
       bqpd.CLOSED + bqpd.FORECAST AS PREV_D_CLOSED_FORECAST,
       bq.PIPELINE - bqpd.PIPELINE AS D_PIPELINE_DIFF,
       bq.BEST - bqpd.BEST AS D_BEST_DIFF,
       bq.FORECAST - bqpd.FORECAST AS D_FORECAST_DIFF,
       bq.CLOSED - bqpd.CLOSED AS D_CLOSED_DIFF,
       (bq.PIPELINE + bq.BEST) - (bqpd.PIPELINE + bqpd.BEST) AS D_PIPE_BEST_DIFF,
       (bq.CLOSED + bq.FORECAST) - (bqpd.CLOSED + bqpd.FORECAST) AS D_CLOSED_FORECAST_DIFF,

       bqpw.PIPELINE AS PREV_W_PIPELINE,
       bqpw.BEST AS PREV_W_BEST,
       bqpw.FORECAST AS PREV_W_FORECAST,
       bqpw.CLOSED AS PREV_W_CLOSED,
       bqpw.PIPELINE + bqpw.BEST AS PREV_W_PIPE_BEST,
       bqpw.CLOSED + bqpw.FORECAST AS PREV_W_CLOSED_FORECAST,
       bq.PIPELINE - bqpw.PIPELINE AS W_PIPELINE_DIFF,
       bq.BEST - bqpw.BEST AS W_BEST_DIFF,
       bq.FORECAST - bqpw.FORECAST AS W_FORECAST_DIFF,
       bq.CLOSED - bqpw.CLOSED AS W_CLOSED_DIFF,
       (bq.PIPELINE + bq.BEST) - (bqpw.PIPELINE + bqpw.BEST) AS W_PIPE_BEST_DIFF,
       (bq.CLOSED + bq.FORECAST) - (bqpw.CLOSED + bqpw.FORECAST) AS W_CLOSED_FORECAST_DIFF,

       bqpm.PIPELINE AS PREV_M_PIPELINE,
       bqpm.BEST AS PREV_M_BEST,
       bqpm.FORECAST AS PREV_M_FORECAST,
       bqpm.CLOSED AS PREV_M_CLOSED,
       bqpm.PIPELINE + bqpm.BEST AS PREV_M_PIPE_BEST,
       bqpm.CLOSED + bqpm.FORECAST AS PREV_M_CLOSED_FORECAST,
       bq.PIPELINE - bqpm.PIPELINE AS M_PIPELINE_DIFF,
       bq.BEST - bqpm.BEST AS M_BEST_DIFF,
       bq.FORECAST - bqpm.FORECAST AS M_FORECAST_DIFF,
       bq.CLOSED - bqpm.CLOSED AS M_CLOSED_DIFF,
       (bq.PIPELINE + bq.BEST) - (bqpm.PIPELINE + bqpm.BEST) AS M_PIPE_BEST_DIFF,
       (bq.CLOSED + bq.FORECAST) - (bqpm.CLOSED + bqpm.FORECAST) AS M_CLOSED_FORECAST_DIFF,

       bqpq.PIPELINE AS PREV_Q_PIPELINE,
       bqpq.BEST AS PREV_Q_BEST,
       bqpq.FORECAST AS PREV_Q_FORECAST,
       bqpq.CLOSED AS PREV_Q_CLOSED,
       bqpq.PIPELINE + bqpq.BEST AS PREV_Q_PIPE_BEST,
       bqpq.CLOSED + bqpq.FORECAST AS PREV_Q_CLOSED_FORECAST,
       bq.PIPELINE - bqpq.PIPELINE AS Q_PIPELINE_DIFF,
       bq.BEST - bqpq.BEST AS Q_BEST_DIFF,
       bq.FORECAST - bqpq.FORECAST AS Q_FORECAST_DIFF,
       bq.CLOSED - bqpq.CLOSED AS Q_CLOSED_DIFF,
       (bq.PIPELINE + bq.BEST) - (bqpq.PIPELINE + bqpq.BEST) AS Q_PIPE_BEST_DIFF,
       (bq.CLOSED + bq.FORECAST) - (bqpq.CLOSED + bqpq.FORECAST) AS Q_CLOSED_FORECAST_DIFF,

       bqpy.PIPELINE AS PREV_Y_PIPELINE,
       bqpy.BEST AS PREV_Y_BEST,
       bqpy.FORECAST AS PREV_Y_FORECAST,
       bqpy.CLOSED AS PREV_Y_CLOSED,
       bqpy.PIPELINE + bqpy.BEST AS PREV_Y_PIPE_BEST,
       bqpy.CLOSED + bqpy.FORECAST AS PREV_Y_CLOSED_FORECAST,
       bq.PIPELINE - bqpy.PIPELINE AS Y_PIPELINE_DIFF,
       bq.BEST - bqpy.BEST AS Y_BEST_DIFF,
       bq.FORECAST - bqpy.FORECAST AS Y_FORECAST_DIFF,
       bq.CLOSED - bqpy.CLOSED AS Y_CLOSED_DIFF,
       (bq.PIPELINE + bq.BEST) - (bqpy.PIPELINE + bqpy.BEST) AS Y_PIPE_BEST_DIFF,
       (bq.CLOSED + bq.FORECAST) - (bqpy.CLOSED + bqpy.FORECAST) AS Y_CLOSED_FORECAST_DIFF,

       bq.ROW_COUNT,
       bqp.ROW_COUNT AS PREV_ROW_COUNT,
       bq.ROW_COUNT - bqp.ROW_COUNT AS NET_ROWS_ADDED

FROM basequery bq
LEFT JOIN SNAPSHOTS ss ON ss.TIMESTAMP = bq.SS_TIMESTAMP AND ss.TABLE_NAME = 'EDGE_FORECAST'

LEFT JOIN basequery bqp ON bqp.SS_TIMESTAMP = ss.PREV_TIMESTAMP
                       AND bqp.EDGE_VP = bq.EDGE_VP
                       AND bqp.EDGE_RM = bq.EDGE_RM
                       AND bqp.EDGE_ASM = bq.EDGE_ASM

LEFT JOIN basequery bqpf ON bqp.SS_TIMESTAMP = ss.PREV_F_TIMESTAMP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_VP = bq.EDGE_VP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_RM = bq.EDGE_RM
                        AND bqp.EDGE_ASM = bq.EDGE_ASM

LEFT JOIN basequery bqph ON bqp.SS_TIMESTAMP = ss.PREV_H_TIMESTAMP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_VP = bq.EDGE_VP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_RM = bq.EDGE_RM
                        AND bqp.EDGE_ASM = bq.EDGE_ASM

LEFT JOIN basequery bqpd ON bqp.SS_TIMESTAMP = ss.PREV_D_TIMESTAMP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_VP = bq.EDGE_VP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_RM = bq.EDGE_RM
                        AND bqp.EDGE_ASM = bq.EDGE_ASM

LEFT JOIN basequery bqpw ON bqp.SS_TIMESTAMP = ss.PREV_W_TIMESTAMP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_VP = bq.EDGE_VP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_RM = bq.EDGE_RM
                        AND bqp.EDGE_ASM = bq.EDGE_ASM

LEFT JOIN basequery bqpm ON bqp.SS_TIMESTAMP = ss.PREV_M_TIMESTAMP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_VP = bq.EDGE_VP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_RM = bq.EDGE_RM
                        AND bqp.EDGE_ASM = bq.EDGE_ASM

LEFT JOIN basequery bqpq ON bqp.SS_TIMESTAMP = ss.PREV_Q_TIMESTAMP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_VP = bq.EDGE_VP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_RM = bq.EDGE_RM
                        AND bqp.EDGE_ASM = bq.EDGE_ASM

LEFT JOIN basequery bqpy ON bqp.SS_TIMESTAMP = ss.PREV_Y_TIMESTAMP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_VP = bq.EDGE_VP
                        AND bqp.EDGE_RM = bq.EDGE_RM
                        AND bqp.EDGE_ASM = bq.EDGE_ASM

ORDER BY ss.TIMESTAMP DESC,
         bq.EDGE_VP ASC,
         bq.EDGE_RM ASC,
         bq.EDGE_ASM ASC
```

Comment: Explain why the close vote, please.

Comment: Ignore the close vote.  Some people mistakenly think that all complex SQL problems belong on the DBA site.

Answer (score 3):

For your first query (the `select distinct`), you want an index on:  `SS_EDGE_FORECAST(SS_TIMESTAMP, EDGE_VP, EDGE_RM, EDGE_ASM)`.  That should help with the analytic function.  Four individual columns won't be of much help.

You can include the additional columns used in the expression as well as later keys in the index.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same thing before posting this question. I created that index, but it still isn't being used. You can see it in the second screenshot image, at the bottom.

Comment: **OH!** Maybe I need the ID column in that index as well. This table has a compound primary key, with two columns. (ID, and SS_TIMESTAMP)

Comment: I figured out why the indexes were not being used ... I typo'd my LEFT JOINS in a horrible way, but also difficult to notice. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

AS @Gordon wrote having index on each column does much sense in your case.
Oracle will not use more than one index to access a table (with exception when you have several OR predicates). So your option is to have a multi-column index.

Also some indexes can not be used - for example because NULL values are not indexed in single column indexes.

Try to use:

```
alter session set index_cost_adj=1;
```

This will reduce cost of using an index in your session. If the index *is not used* in such a case, then it probably *can not be used*.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by:

**a)** Moving the smaller subquery into a materialized view with constraints and indexes. (This is a data warehouse snapshot reporting operation, and the table is updated daily at 2:00am, so I don't need to worry about constant "rebuild" performance during the day.)

**b)** FIXING THE COPY/PASTE FAIL IN MY LEFT JOINS
Good heavens ... when I finally noticed this oversight, I wanted to punch myself in the face.

```
LEFT JOIN basequery bqp ON bqp.SS_TIMESTAMP = ss.PREV_TIMESTAMP
                       AND bqp.EDGE_VP = bq.EDGE_VP
                       AND bqp.EDGE_RM = bq.EDGE_RM
                       AND bqp.EDGE_ASM = bq.EDGE_ASM

LEFT JOIN basequery bqpf ON bqp.SS_TIMESTAMP = ss.PREV_F_TIMESTAMP -- problem here
                        AND bqp.EDGE_VP = bq.EDGE_VP               -- should be
                        AND bqp.EDGE_RM = bq.EDGE_RM               -- bqpf.EDGE_RM etc.
                        AND bqp.EDGE_ASM = bq.EDGE_ASM
```

Every single one of my dozen-or-so LEFT JOINs had this problem.
No wonder the server was choking on this query whenever I tested it.

After fixing the LEFT JOIN typos, and reinforcing with some helpful materialized views, the query executes in 0.1 seconds - which is very exciting for me, considering just how much heavy-lifting this query will do, and how useful it will be.